# Better have one long or multiple short UDP sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I want to send regularly UDP messages through sockets.

Is it better to use one socket, or to recreate a socket for each message and close them just after?

Since UDP is stateless, does it even change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting to receive anything over the socket, it had better exist for the entire time over which you're expecting to receive.

If you're expecting to send multiple messages without receiving any replies you already have a design mistake, but there doesn't seem to be a good reason why you would keep opening and closing UDP sockets for that purpose. Surely it makes more sense to keep the socket open as long as necessary?

Comment: It is no design mistake since it is just a router sending statistics. The question is does is really make more sens to have a infinitly long socket, or is it better to create short ones?

Comment: Let's turn that around. Does it really make sense *not* to have an 'infinitely long socket'? and create a new socket per transmission? and possibly fail? when if you already had the socket you couldn't fail?

Answer (score 1):

Since UDP is a packet-oriented protocol, there is no "connection" to open or to close. If you are going to send a lot of messages to a particular address you can call `connect` on a UDP socket, and then use `send` and `recv` to communicate instead of `sendto` and `recvfrom`. This way you don't have to specify the address where you want the data sent on every function call, but that doesn't mean that a connection is established.

So, whether it's better to create one socket and reuse it, or create a new one every time, depends more on your programming style: If you create lots of sockets and store them for long periods of time without using them, you may eventually run out of sockets. Then again, asking the operating system to create new sockets frequently may become a performance bottleneck if you do it in a tight loop.

Comment: So the socket creation process is just storing parameters to be used in the send function?

Comment: I had my terms jumbled: you have to call `socket` to get an fd so you can talk with the OS. Calling `connect` only stores parameters.